# Can I ignore a `Filter chain halted as :set_user rendered or redirected`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, exception

Since my tests (and dev output) were getting a bit out of hand, I modified the plain old `set_user` filter of my `UsersController` like

```
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) rescue render(json: { message: 'User not found' }, status: 404)
end
```

which (crudely) gets rid of the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception and proceeds to render a plain old 404 message. Now, except for the warning I get regarding the filter halting processing, there seem to be no visible side effects, and I can avoid rescuing the AR exception in all my spec examples.

I'm wondering if this is an acceptable practice, and, if not, what a better solution might look like.

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, this is quite crude. It will catch any exception and return the JSON you specified, although it might not be a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error.

I would recommend using `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :method_name` in your ApplicationController, which will rescue just that type of error and respond with the appropriate JSON.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that I should be catching the right exception, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Additionally this will mean that your controllers will not have to have any error handling as it will be handled by the ApplicationController.